# how to disable fxcop analysis in sonar

Tags: sonarqube, fxcop

I am trying to analyze code coverage for .NET project.
Here is my sonar.project file.

```
# Project identification
sonar.projectKey=ABC
sonar.projectVersion=trunk
sonar.projectName=ABCD



# Info required for Sonar 
sonar.sources=.
sonar.language=cs
sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8
sonar.visualstudio.enable=true
sonar.visualstudio.testProjectPattern=UnitTest



#Core C# Settings
sonar.dotnet.visualstudio.solution.file=./MySample.sln
#sonar.silverlight.4.mscorlib.location=C:/Program Files (x86)/Reference Assemblies/Microsoft/Framework/Silverlight/v5.0
sonar.dotnet.excludeGeneratedCode=true
sonar.dotnet.4.0.sdk.directory=C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework64/v4.0.30319
sonar.dotnet.version=4.0 

# To prevent any issues while analyzing multiple solutions containing projects with similar keys
# Will be set by default to safe starting at version 2.2: http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONARDOTNT-339
sonar.dotnet.key.generation.strategy=safe

sonar.cs.opencover.reportsPaths=C:/openCoverAnalysis/Sample.xml

# FXCop 
sonar.fxcop.mode=skip
```

> sonar.fxcop.mode=skip

is not working. Am I missing anything ?

SonarQube version 4.5

Comment: Which version of the C# plugins are you using?

Comment: C# plugin version 3.3,  someone said it sonar.fxcop.mode is disabled since 3.0. I disabled fxcop related rules and it started working.